# How to get jqgrid cell value when editing row?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I can edit jqgrid row as follows. When I edit inline, this release date contains html content.

```
{name:'releaseDate',index:'releaseDate', width:55,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
```

jsonReader : {
            root: "collection",
            page: "startPage",
            total: "totalPage",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id"
        }

I gave option to change Release date value by function as follows. When I edit using this function actual date is taken.Thus when I am trying to post data, this value is not binding. Do I need to get Html content here? How can I post data ?

```
function setValuesToJqGrid() {
var myGrid = jq("#grid");
    if(detailGridId==(i+1)){
    myGrid.jqGrid('setCell', detailGridId, 'releaseDate', jq('#setDate').val());
```

}

Please anyone can help me?

Comment: Please write always the **version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and the **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Your question is about **getting** the cell value, but you don't post the code, which uses any "get" method. Moreover, it's important to know **where** you need to get the cell value. Inside of which *callback*/*event* you try to get the cell value? You write about "row editing". Do you use "inline editing" or another editing mode?

Comment: I am using 3.6 version of  free jqGrid. It is not a commercial one. I want to use both inline editing and editing through method. When I used inline editing I can post data without any issue. But if I use a method to edit the cell then I can not post data. I checked value of the cell when I used inline editing, it was a html content. But when I used method to edit cell then it contains my actual data.

Comment: I suppose that you entered **wrong version number**. jqGrid 3.6 is about 8 years old and I don't believe that you use the version. If you really want to use the retro version, that I can't help you. The last version of "jqGrid" product is 4.7 published at the end of 2014. After that exist two main **forks** of jqGrid under the following names: ["free jqGrid"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, and **commercial** ["Guriddo jqGrid JS"](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which develop Tony Tomov. During the time after 2014 both forks have many different features.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Guriddo jqGrid JavaScript](http://www.guriddo.net) you can visit our documentation.

For Inline editing you may want to [look here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#inline-editing)

For Cell editing you may want to [look here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#cell-editing)

The method setCell you mentioned is not applicable if you use inline or cell editing - the appropriate methods are described in the links provided.

Comment: Thank you Tony. But I am not  using this jqgrid.